# Linear congruential generator in C++

Tags: c++, random, generator

I wrote a simple program (tried to implement the Linear congruential generator actually), but I'm not quite sure it works like it should.

I wanted to generate 250 number from [0,1] using my generator. However, it seems that instead of random numbers, I get equal values ..

How to improve it / what I did wrong?

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

static const double A = 0.001342;
static const double C = 0.00025194;
static const double RAND_MAX = 1.0;

double rand()
{
    static double prev = 0;
    prev = A * prev + fmod(C, RAND_MAX);
    return prev;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
    std::cout << rand() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
0.00025194
0.000252278
0.000252279
0.000252279
0.000252279
0.000252279
```

Switching to `int` instead of `double`, however gives some nice results:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

static const int A = 5;
static const int C = 3;
static const int RAND_MAX = 8;

double rand()
{
    static int prev = 1;
    prev = A * prev + (C % RAND_MAX);
    return prev;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    std::cout << rand() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
8
43
218
1093
5468
27343
136718
683593
3.41797e+06
1.70898e+07
8.54492e+07
4.27246e+08
2.13623e+09
2.09122e+09
1.86615e+09
7.40836e+08
-5.90786e+08
1.34104e+09
...
```

But I need it for generating random double numbers, greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 1 :(

Comment: I'd suggest keeping `A < C` and using similar exponents when in scientific notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the program, it's the choice of numbers.

`prev` is in the beginning equal to zero, so the first number becomes `C`.

Then, `prev` is equal to `C`, which makes prev `A*C + C`. However, `A*C` is so small, that when adding it as a floating point to the previous one, significant digits are shifted out and you're left with what you had before.

You can read more on [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Thank you, will read it in a while, but how about my problem? Is it possible to choose A and C that the code will generate random floating point numbers? If so, what are those numbers should be?

Comment: @yak Technically speaking (and I'm not really good at this :) ), `A*C` would have it's exponent similar to the one of the `C` itself. I'd recommend making `A` larger and closer compared to `C`. Integers give nicer results, because adding an integer is much different to adding two floats - no shifts occur, no imprecision can be felt.

Comment: Hmm, thanks! Changing `A` to `0.9`, `C` to `0.01` and `prev` to `0.0001` quite helped actually :) However, with my set size (I need 250 random numbers, geez) I still have some repeated numbers.

Comment: @yak you don't have to do it alone. First of all, you may get better results when using `int`s for generating the numbers, and division of interval is not a problem then. Second, you can help yourself with some numbers that are already in use :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use floating point arithmetic for LCG's.  Floating point is inherently imprecise, and can lead to undesirable behaviors such as fixed point convergence or interleaved short subcycles.  With integer arithmetic, number theory can tell you what parameters are guaranteed to achieve full cycle, i.e., every value between 0 and M-1 (where M is your modulus) **will** be attained.  See the [Wikipedia article on LCGs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) for the full-cycle parameter requirements and a table of commonly used parameters.

Second, you have misinterpreted the LCG formula.  It should be:

```
prev = (A * prev + C) % M;
```

Third, with your current choice of parameters you won't run into this but in general your intermediate calculations should be done with `long` to avoid  overflow.  The `%` operation will bring the answer back to an `int`, but if you stick with `int` arithmetic the multiplication may not yield the mathematically correct value which assures full cycle length and proper distributional behavior.

Comment: `prev = (A * prev + C) % (RAND_MAX + 1);` (approximately)  as RAND_MAX is defined as one of the possible results.